# Calling QDialog from another window

Tags: python-3.x, dialog, pyqt5, qdialog

I'am programming a small app for database handling and thought I give pyqt5 a try since I have some experience with PySide from the (very old) past. So far it worked like a charm, but now I want to open a dialog if the user decides to create a new database entry. This happens from a QMainWindow. On a sidenote: My intention is to have Dialog modal so both widgets will be alive at the same time.

The problem is that as soon as I click the button that should open the dialog my program terminates without exception or anything. I'm a bit at loss here...

This is the test Dialog I wrote:

```
class ColorDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, Color=None, parent=None):
        super(self).__init__(parent)
        self.result = ""

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        btn_ok = QPushButton("OK", self)
        layout.addWidget(btn_ok)
        btn_ok.clicked.connect(self._ok)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)

    def _ok(self):
        self.result = "1"

    def get_result(self):
        return self.result
```

I call this dialog with the following method:

```
def _new_color(self):
    cp = ColorDialog(self)
    cp.exec_()
    print(cp.get_result())
```

I also tried show() instead of exec_() to the same effect.

The main window is called like this:

```
def main():

    db = DBService()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    UI = MainWindow(db, "eng")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What am I doing wrong here? I feel I miss something fundamental here...
Thanks for your help

Comment: Change `super(self).__init__(parent)` to `super(ColorDialog, self).__init__(parent)` or `super().__init__(parent)` in python3

Comment: Congrats, now I feel really stupid ;) Thanks  If you make this a short answer I'll accept it.

Comment: This is a typographical error and for me it is off-topic (it should be eliminated), it does not deserve an answer since it is a very particular problem, answer it if you wish.